# Is it possible to dump JavaScript errors to a div in HTML?

Tags: javascript, html, error-handling

I'm writing a game and I've got a console for developers to interact with JavaScript methods in the game. I have a problem though; I can't figure out how to drop JavaScript errors to the console. Is there anyway to write errors to a div or HTML element?

Comment: `I can figure out how` ... Do you mean can't?

Comment: I think he really meant 'can', he says he already knows how to drop messages to the console

Comment: I meant can't sorry guys

Comment: http://jsbin.com/ actually shows JavaScript errors and console output in a div. I'm still not sure how it works, though.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It sounds like you already have the ability to execute JS working, and just need to capture error output?  If so, you should be able to do so by wrapping your execution code in a `try ... catch` block:

```
var result;

try {
    result = eval($("#console-input").val());
} catch (ex) {
    if (ex !== null && typeof ex !== "undefined") {
        if (ex.message) ex = ex.message;
    } else {
        ex = "An unknown error occurred.";
    }

    result = ex;
}

$("#console-output").append($("<p/>").text(result));
$("#console-input").val("");
```

This will add the result of the code to an output div if no error occurs.  If an error *does* occur, it will instead output either the error message (if any) or "An unknown error occurred."

Answer (score 0):

Custom defined JavaScript errors are output with the throw command.  If you want to input those errors into a div then use the innerHTML method instead of throw and immediately return from the executing function.

Answer (score 0):

```
konsole = document.createElement('ul');
konsole.id = 'console';
document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].appendChild(konsole);

    function log(konsole, message, level)
    {
        if (undefined === level) level = 0;
        messageElem = document.createElement('li');
        messageElem.className = 'level-' + level;
        messageElem.innerHTML = message;
        konsole.appendChild(messageElem);
    };


document.getElementById('console')

log(document.getElementById('console'), ': )');
```

Then it's just about CSS...